# Código em C simplesmente fecha

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void recebeNumCartas(int *nAlice, int *nBeatriz){

    scanf("%d %d", nAlice, nBeatriz);

}

int achaMenor(int nAlice, int nBeatriz, int menor){

    menor = nAlice;

    if (nBeatriz < nAlice){
        menor = nBeatriz;
    }

    return menor;
}

int realizaTroca(int nAlice, int nBeatriz, int menor){

    int cartasAlice[nAlice];
    int cartasBeatriz[nBeatriz];
    int troca[menor * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < nAlice; ++i){
        scanf("%d", cartasAlice[i]);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < nBeatriz; ++j){
        scanf("%d", cartasBeatriz[j]);
    }
}

int main(void){

    int nAlice = 0;
    int nBeatriz = 0;
    int menor = 0;

    recebeNumCartas(&nAlice, &nBeatriz);
    menor = achaMenor(nAlice, nBeatriz, menor);

    realizaTroca(nAlice, nBeatriz, menor);

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Estou fazendo um exercício com o código acima, mas depois que o primeiro for loop da função realizaTroca é executado o programa encerra sem nenhuma mensagem de erro. Preciso de ajuda para entender oque está acontecendo.

Answer (score 4):

Seu código está retornando um `segmentation fault` na leitura do vetor.

Segue a documentação da função:

```
int scanf ( const char * format, ... );
```

> Reads data from stdin and stores them according to the parameter format into the locations pointed by the additional arguments.
>
> The additional arguments should point to already allocated objects of the type specified by their corresponding format specifier within the format string.

Isto diz que os argumentos adicionais da função devem ser ponteiros (ou um endereço de memória) para objetos já alocados do mesmo tipo da função.

Sendo assim o seu problema pode ser resolvido simplesmente colocando o operador `&` no `scanf` dessa forma:

```
scanf("%d", &cartasAlice[i]);
scanf("%d", &cartasBeatriz[j]);
```

No início do código você já estava usando seu código sem o `&` e funcionou, na seguinte instrução:

```
scanf("%d %d", nAlice, nBeatriz);
```

Isso ocorre pois as variáveis `nAlice` e `nBeatriz` já conterem endereços de memória. Veja a declaração da função:

```
void recebeNumCartas(int *nAlice, int *nBeatriz)
```

Estes `*` indicam que esta variável deve conter um endereço de memória para uma variável do tipo inteiro. Este endereço está sendo passado na chamada, com o `&` nesta linha:

```
recebeNumCartas(&nAlice, &nBeatriz);
```

Sendo assim o `scanf` está recebendo exatamente o que ele espera.

Comment: Em qual linha isso ocorre? Estou meio perdido

Comment: ainda estou editando a pergunta, vou explicar tudo que está ocorrendo

Comment: entendeu o que está acontecendo agora?

Comment: Entendi, vou prestar mais atenção nestes detalhes, obrigado!